# Sort a dataframe based on a column with string values and date

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataset.

[image]

I want to sort the dataset in such a way that the districts go in ascending order and for each district, it has to be sorted by date from 1982-01-01 to 2019-12-31.

For example:

| DATE | DISTRICT | ...other features... |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1982-01-01 | Achham |  |
| --- | --- |  |
| 2019-12-31 | Achham |  |
| --- | --- |  |
| 1982-01-01 | Udaypur |  |
| --- | --- |  |
| 2019-12-31 | Udaypur |  |

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`sort_values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html):

```
df = df.sort_values(by=['DATE','DISTRICT'])
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer.

```
df.sort_values(by=['DISTRICT', 'DATE'], ascending=[True, True], inplace=True)
```

It was simple.